# Enabling CORS in GeoServer propulsed by docker:jetty

Tags: geoserver, cors, jetty, docker

I am trying to enable CORS in a docker/jetty context for Geoserver. I modified the [geoserver Dockefile](https://github.com/georchestra/georchestra/blob/master/geoserver/webapp/src/docker/Dockerfile) as follows :

First i used a very simple regexp to insert in /usr/local/jetty/etc/webdefault.xml the CrossOriginFilter lines, just before the last line :

```
RUN sed -i 's/<\/web-app>/<filter>\n<filter-name>cross-origin<\/filter-name>\n<filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter<\/filter-class>\n<\/filter>\n<filter-mapping>\n<filter-name>cross-origin<\/filter-name>\n<url-pattern>\/\*<\/url-pattern>\n<\/filter-mapping>\n<\/web-app>/g' /usr/local/jetty/etc/webdefault.xml
```

the file webdefault.xml thus contains the following lines :

```
<filter>
<filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then i activated the use of servlets in the java command :

```
RUN java -jar "$JETTY_HOME/start.jar" --create-startd --add-to-start=jmx,jmx-remote,stats,jndi,servlets
```

Finally, I tried to check that everything was working as expected, with the curl command :

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://example.com" https://georchestra-docker.umrthema.univ-fcomte.fr/geoserver/wfs\?service\=WFS\&version\=2.0.0\&request\=GetFeature\&typenames\=sf:bugsites\&filter\=%3Cfes:Filter%20xmlns:fes\=%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%3E%3Cfes:ResourceId%20rid\=%22bugsites.3%22/%3E%3C/fes:Filter%3E
```

The complete server response is :

```
*   Trying 127.0.1.1...
* Connected to georchestra-docker.umrthema.univ-fcomte.fr (127.0.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: georchestra-docker.umrthema.univ-fcomte.fr (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: C=FR,L=Besançon,O=Université de Besancon,CN=georchestra-docker.umrthema.univ-fcomte.fr
*    start date: Tue, 11 Jul 2017 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Wed, 15 Jul 2020 12:00:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=NL,ST=Noord-Holland,L=Amsterdam,O=TERENA,CN=TERENA SSL CA 3
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET /geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=sf:bugsites&filter=%3Cfes:Filter%20xmlns:fes=%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%3E%3Cfes:ResourceId%20rid=%22bugsites.3%22/%3E%3C/fes:Filter%3E HTTP/1.1
> Host: georchestra-docker.umrthema.univ-fcomte.fr
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://example.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
< Content-Length: 505
< Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Server: Jetty(9.4.7.v20170914)
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node012ntghgewu9uh1bps5h165qihp612.node0;Path=/
< Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Date: Wed, 04 Apr 2018 09:04:30 GMT
```

**Everything looks ok, but the process ends with this error :**

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 https://georchestra-docker.umrthema.univ-fcomte.fr/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">    
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="namespace">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Unknown namespace [sf]</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

What is going on ?

Comment: When using GeoServer/Jetty with Docker I use `xmlstarlet` to modify XML files; here is an example to enable CORS: https://gist.github.com/dbaston/1806a5b97e51f7a90fdb3f7c35ddd08b

Comment: most docker versions of geoserver use tomcat, and not jetty. which repository do you use ? is it on the docker hub ?

Comment: I usually write my own, to include the extensions/modules that I need.